# PHP Class Function for hashing

Tags: php, salt, crypt

```
public function kryptonite($string){
   $salt = "";
   $salt_vars = array_merge(range("A","Z"),range("a","z"),range(0,9));
   for($i=0;$i < 22;$i++){
        $salt.= $salt_vars[array_rand($salt_vars)];
   }
   return crypt($string, '$6$'.$salt);
  }
```

This returns on refresh:

```
$6$vnuqcEA70$CHWmPVsDVb.lVpq1PNsDn7.0fSmBX6FU2PlofK6dJOH7FQp6EdSsde3Aw6to8fY1L01/WOcWz8OIE0OxK1LTj.
$6$7lmp9sD4g$I0fAcDjno2Lf255gg6TxTLt9TRwR803ZXiU9BOWJXhWrGbJdPJ3LvAW9w2KbRZ/3EDSSbFrgF7rV7DdB0VliA0
```

If you closely at the first few lines it's changing constantly. I don't think Hashing is suppose to constantly change! So technically I'll never be able to test against this. Can someone help me with my `kryptonite` crypt function or explain to me what went wrong really.

Comment: Why do you not just use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/password_hash)? Also, `$6$...` is an invalid hash string. The SHA512 hash string has the format `$6$rounds=N$hashstringhere$`. You should [read the documentation](http://php.net/crypt) properly!

Comment: 1. Do not use `array_rand` for security. 2. Use password hashing API.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I thought default was 5000 for rounds so you didn't have to declare it unless modifying it. And I can't use password_hash yet my PHP Version is 5.2.* (000webhost) sorry to say. I'm getting some money to buy hosting from GoDaddy so then I'll change the functions to support the new PHP

Comment: @EasyBB Then use the [compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: I'll read more into tomorrow Thanks Sverri.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, hashing *is* supposed to randomly change - it's called random salting.  Your crypt function is creating a random salt which is fed to the SHA-512 hasher.

The output of `crypt()` includes the salt value, which you would then use when hashing a password to compare it to the stored hash.

```
public function kryptonite($string, $salt = null){
    if ($salt === null) {
        $salt = "";
        $salt_vars = array_merge(range("A","Z"),range("a","z"),range(0,9));
        for($i=0;$i < 22;$i++){
            $salt.= $salt_vars[array_rand($salt_vars)];
        }
        $salt = '$6$' . $salt;
    }
    return crypt($string, $salt);
}
```

To use this, you'd just do the following:

```
$storedHash = '.....'; // fetched from database
$inputPassword = '.....'; // from the user

$salt = preg_match('/\$[0-9]\$(.+)\$/')[1]; // php 5.4+

if (kryptonite($inputPassword, $salt) == $storedHash) {
    //.... success
}
```

Note that the array_random implementation of creating a random salt isn't cryptographically secure - it'd be better to use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` or `mt_rand()` or such.

Comment: I don't have 5.4+ :( Also I'd like to note I am teaching myself all of this with the occasional help from SO. I'm going to college for this and I haven't started this course. I usually jump ahead so I don't have to listen to the professors :)

Comment: You should really upgrade... but anyway, the 5.4 bit is just the ability access array members directly from the result of the function call.  Otherwise, you have to do `$result = preg_match('...'); $salt = $result[1];`

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get the same result when using `array_rand()` I'd recommend something like this if you're going to use **salts** and need a two way encryption

```
function parse($action, $string) {
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";

    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', "random encryption key that must stay the same");

    // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', "ARANDOMIV"), 0, 16);

    if($action == 'encrypt') {
        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        $output = base64_encode($output);
    } else if( $action == 'decrypt' ){
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to encrypt or decrypt that is why I used crypt as its a one-way string hashing algorithm, though plus 1 for the openssl stuff man

Comment: @EasyBB , hash cannot be decrypted.

Comment: Then why do you classify your actions as encrypt and decrypt

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the same *hashes* when you're using the `array_rand()` function. The result needs to be deterministic.

Is there a reason why [`sha1()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.sha1.php) isn't good enough?

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, I watched a video on this to help me and this is what the guy said to do. Have any better solutions sir? `sha1()` is accessible to brute force. md5 and sha1 is even stated not to use it in the php docs

Comment: @EasyBB Was it a video by a competent software developer or some kid off YouTube?

Comment: He seemed competent HAHA owns or did own www.worldofwebcraft.com

Comment: What are you hashing? If it's for a password, you're doing it wrong. If you're after hashing (for example to quickly compare 2 files) then use an existing hashing function. I can't find in the docs where PHP states not to use sha1 for hashing (except for passwords, as mentioned above).

Comment: Well it's for password hashing not file comparison. `Note: Secure password hashing
It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See `<a href="http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash">here</a> `for details.`

Comment: @EasyBB That's the docs stating not to use it in a certain context, not recommending against it outright. Anyway, if this is for passwords, [use bycrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

Comment: what is wrong with crypt? Could i use my original function and instead use another hash to use with other credentials of the user as the salt?